# Color empty columns in tables

Tags: tables, color

I would like to color these empty columns, but I couldn't find a way to do it. I tried already defining my own column type, however, inserting it destroys the normal look of empty columns.

Here my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{||l c||} 
        \hline
        \rowcolor{black!10}
        Column 1 & Column 2 \\ [0.7ex] 
        \hline\hline
        \rowcolor{green!20}
        Entry 1 & Entry 2 \\ 
        \hline
        \rowcolor{green!25}
        Entry 3 & Entry 4 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I would like to color the outer columns black.
Thank you!

**Solution**: For black coloring, thick border lines are enough. For other colors, see my *colortbl* solution.

Comment: Take a look at the `hhline` package, if I remember correctly, it does support coloured double lines.

Comment: Which  outer columns? Maybe you mean the space between the rules of double rules?

Comment: @Bernard exactly, I mean the space between the outer double rules.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you, I will look into that.

Comment: If it's to be black, this simply means a very thick vertical rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width 5pt}l c!{\vrule width 5pt}} 
        \hline
        \rowcolor{black!10}
        Column 1 & Column 2 \\ [0.7ex] 
        \hline\hline
        \rowcolor{green!20}
        Entry 1 & Entry 2 \\ 
        \hline
        \rowcolor{green!25}
        Entry 3 & Entry 4 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, if I've well understood what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width \dimexpr\doublerulesep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}l c!{\vrule width \dimexpr\doublerulesep+2arrayrulewidth\relax}}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{black!10}
        Column 1 & Column 2 \\ [0.7ex]
        \hline\hline
        \rowcolor{green!20}
        Entry 1 & Entry 2 \\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{green!25}
        Entry 3 & Entry 4 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant:

```
\begin{center}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}\begin{tabular}{{@{\vrule width \dimexpr\doublerulesep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}c@{\vrule width \dimexpr\doublerulesep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}}}
    \begin{tabular}{!{}l c!{}}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{black!10}
        Column 1 & Column 2 \\ [0.7ex]
        \hline\hline
        \rowcolor{green!20}
        Entry 1 & Entry 2 \\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{green!25}
        Entry 3 & Entry 4 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok after @Skillmon's tip I looked into that package and found a reference to the *colortbl* package, which solved it:

```
        \doublerulesepcolor{black}
        \begin{tabular}{||l c||}
        \doublerulesepcolor{white}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{black!10}
            Column 1 & Column 2 \\ [0.7ex] 
            \hline\hline
            \rowcolor{green!20}
            Entry 1 & Entry 2 \\ 
            \hline
            \rowcolor{green!25}
            Entry 3 & Entry 4 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
```

[image: Result]

You can have quite some fun with this:

```
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}\arrayrulecolor{blue}
    \setlength\doublerulesep{2pt}\doublerulesepcolor{yellow}
    \begin{tabular}{||l c||}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{black!10}
        Column 1 & Column 2 \\ [0.7ex] 
        \hline\hline
        \rowcolor{green!20}
        Entry 1 & Entry 2 \\ 
        \hline
        \rowcolor{green!25}
        Entry 3 & Entry 4 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

[image: Result]

For further reference: [link](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/colortbl/colortbl.pdf)

Comment: note you had already loaded colortbl (that's the main effect of the `[table]` option to `xcolor`)